# How to use cross application authentication with MVC4 and Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I have hosted mvc application inside the web form application. when i try to access MVC view inside the web form application System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is null. how i pass the authenticated user between MVC and webform applications.

Comment: I found the solution from this [This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021863/upgrading-to-asp-net-4-5-mvc-4-forms-authentication-fails